# Writing XML code for multi-app kiosk for Windows desktop

Tags: windows, kiosk

I'm trying to create multi-app kiosk for one of our computer in the office running Windows 10 pro.

It works with Microsoft apps such as Calculator, Internet Explorer, but I'm trying to create one for one of our in-house app and it didn't work. When in kiosk mode, it came up with the app button but with a text of the location to the app itself (eg: `W~C:\path\to\app\app.exe` - I don't know what `W~` means). And when I click on it, nothing happens. With multi-app kiosk, you have to write an XML file to allow which app to run:

```xml
<Profiles>
  <Profile Id="{some id}">
    <AllAppsList>
      <AllowedApps>
        <App DesktopAppPath="C:\path\to\app\app.exe" />
      </AllowedApps>
    </AllAppsList>
    <StartLayout>
      <![CDATA[<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
          <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
            <DefaultLayoutOverride>
              <StartLayoutCollection>
                <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
                  <start:Group Name="TAS">
                    <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="C:\path\to\app\app.exe" />
                  </start:Group> 
                </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
              </StartLayoutCollection>
            </DefaultLayoutOverride>
          </LayoutModificationTemplate>
      ]]>
    </StartLayout>
  </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

I was just wondering if there's something that you need to set in the `<App>` tag to specify the library path/working folder? Is there any documentation about on how to write XML files for multi-app kiosk? I found this on the Microsoft website but not in details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it came up with the app button"? The allowed apps list is used to allow or disallow a given app but not to present it on-screen (unless you set `rs5:AutoLaunch="true"` on that app).

Comment: @KitGrose Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I didn't include the Layout bits. I've included them now. So what I meant was with that layout, it shows my app button in windows start (like when you do a "Pin to start" for an app/program). But instead of showing the app name, it shows "W~C:\path\to\app\app.exe". And when I click on the app, it won't run. And I tried adding rs5:AutoLaunch="true", it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: The application path is _not_ a valid value for `DesktopApplicationID`. The document you linked [says to use the `DesktopApplicationLinkPath` attribute to point to desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps#startlayout). If you want to use the `DesktopApplicationID` attribute you need its user model ID as described on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/start-layout-xml-desktop), but it's probably easier to use the shortcut links instead.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using DesktopApplicationLinkPath but now it came up with no app button at all, just a blank start menu. I thought DesktopApplicationLinkPath is used for .lnk files? Started to wonder whether this multi-app kiosk mode won't work with in-house app

Comment: Yes, to use the link path you’ll need to create a .lnk file first. There’s a section on that second link about provisioning shortcuts. You can use the ID attribute if you prefer but you should get it from a working install as they recommend (that is, set up your Start menu manually then export the config).